# Placing a div below another (using flexbox)

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I am trying to place the `timeAgo` content ("22 seconds ago") just below the `info` content. But, for the styling I am using, `timeAgo` is being pushed towards right.

Here is my markup

```css
.container {
overflow:auto;
}

.post {
height:120px;
width:700px;
margin:120px auto;
background-color:#EFEFEF;
border:1px solid #79CEF4;
display:flex;
justify-content:flex-start;     
}


.photo {
width:80px;
height:80px;
background-color:#99E058;
margin:10px 10px 10px 20px;
align-self:center;
}

.info {

margin: 25px 10px 10px 20px;
align-self:center;
}

.timeAgo {
margin: 80px 10px 10px 20px;
font-size:11px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">

     <div class="post">
        
        <div class="photo"></div>
        <div class="info"><p>This is just a plain simple message!</p></div>
        <div class="timeAgo">22 seconds ago</div>
    
     </div>
    
</div>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The simplest thing to do is adjust the HTML.

```css
.post {
  height: 120px;
  width: 700px;
  margin: 20px auto;
  background-color: #EFEFEF;
  border: 1px solid #79CEF4;
  display: flex;
  align-content: center;
  justify-content: flex-start;
}
.imgwrap {
  text-align: center;
}
.photo {
  width: 80px;
  height: 80px;
  background-color: #99E058;
  margin: 10px 10px 10px 20px;
}
.info {
  margin: 25px 10px 10px 20px;
}
.timeAgo {
  font-size: 11px;
}
```

```html
<div class="post">
  <div class="imgwrap">
    <div class="photo"></div>
    <div class="timeAgo">22 seconds ago</div>
  </div>
  <div class="info">
    <p>This is just a plain simple message!</p>
  </div>


</div>
```

BUT...if you can't do that, you'll have to allow the flex-container to wrap and make the `timeAgo` div be forced to the second 'row'.

One way:

```css
.post {
  height: 120px;
  width: 700px;
  margin: 20px auto;
  background-color: #EFEFEF;
  border: 1px solid #79CEF4;
  display: flex;
  align-content: center;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}
.photo {
  flex: 0 0 80px;
  height: 80px;
  background-color: #99E058;
  margin: 10px 10px 0px 10px;
}
.info {
  flex: 1;
  display: flex;
  align-self: center;
}
.timeAgo {
  flex: 0 0 100%;
  font-size: 11px;
  margin: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="post">

  <div class="photo"></div>


  <div class="info">
    <p>This is just a plain simple message!</p>
  </div>

  <div class="timeAgo">22 seconds ago</div>
</div>
```

Comment: To avoid confusion by future visitors please note that the answer was accepted even though the `.timeAgo` div was positioned under the `.photo` div, not the `.info` div, as required by the question.

Answer (score 73):

This is a much simpler answer. Use `flex-direction: column;`!

```css
.post {
   height:120px;
   width:700px;
   margin:120px auto;
   background-color:#EFEFEF;
   border:1px solid #79CEF4;
   display:flex;
   justify-content:flex-start;  
   flex-direction: column; /*This solves everything*/
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
<div class="post">
    <div class="photo"></div>
    <div class="info"><p>This is just a plain simple message!</p></div>
    <div class="timeAgo">22 seconds ago</div>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: It worked for me. But how can we align the items in the middle of the parent div? Even using align-items center doesn't seems to work

Answer (score -1):

It's not an ideal solution, but still;

```
.timeAgo {
    margin: 80px 10px 10px -260px;
    font-size:11px;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Use:
`flex-wrap: wrap` on the `parent div` and `flex: 1` on the `child div`