# WordPress CSS Sidebar Layout

Tags: css, wordpress

I have a HTML website and an addon blog in WordPress. I have managed to theme my WordPress blog so that it integrates into my website however, I am having layout problems. The blog site is https://www.smilehawthorn.com.au/blog/

The screenshot below is a clip of what it looks like in the mobile view.

[image: THis is a screenshot of a blog I am working on when viewed in Mobile View]

This is the code currently for my style.css. I have tried modifying the code for @media variations but I cant get it to work.

```html
/* Base style */
/**************/

.ac-content-sidebar {
  padding: 5px;
  background: #fff !important;
  background-image: none;
  color: rgb(102, 102, 102);
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}
/* Content */

div#ac-main-content {
  display: block;
  float: left;
  width: 70%;
}

div#ac-main-content a {
  color: #337ab7;
  font-size: unset;
}

div#ac-main-content.ac-full {
  width: 100%;
}

#ac-main-content article {
  width: 100%;
  float: none;
  margin: 0;
  text-align: left;
}

#ac-main-content article.post + article.post {
  margin-top: 35px;
}

#ac-main-content article.post h2 {
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  font-size: 22px;
}

#ac-main-content article.post div.entry {
  margin: 10px 0;
  font-size: 13px;
}

#ac-main-content article.post div.entry ol {
  padding: 0 20px;
}

#ac-main-content article.post div.entry p {
  color: rgb(102, 102, 102);
  font-size: 13px;
  text-align: left;
  padding: 0;
}
/* Sidebar position */

.ac-content-sidebar > aside {
  display: block;
  float: left;
  width: 30%;
  max-width: 250px;
  height: auto;
}

aside.ac-sidebar + div#ac-main-content {
  margin-left: 3%;
}

div#ac-main-content + aside.ac-sidebar {
  margin-left: 3%;
}

/* Sidebar */

aside.ac-sidebar {
  background: #fff !important;
  background-image: none;
  width: 30%;
}

aside.ac-sidebar a {
  color: #78A89C !important;
  font-size: unset;
}

aside.ac-sidebar h3 {
  font-size: 22px;
  color: #333333;
}

aside.ac-sidebar > div {
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}

aside.ac-sidebar form#searchform input#s {
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 150px;
}

aside.ac-sidebar h3 {
  margin-bottom: 5px;
}

aside.ac-sidebar .widget,
aside.ac-sidebar .widget-title {
  position: float;
  height: auto;
}

aside.ac-sidebar .widget {
  padding: 0 0 5px 5px;
  text-align: left;
}

aside.ac-sidebar ul {
  padding-left: 0;
  min-height: auto !important;
}

aside.ac-sidebar ul > li {
  float: none;
  list-style: outside none none;
  color: rgb(102, 102, 102) !important;
}

aside.ac-sidebar label {
  color: inherit;
}




/**********************/
/* Your customization */
/**********************/

/* Add your rules here */
html {
    margin-top: 0 !important;
    padding-top: 0 !important;
}
body {
    margin-top: 0 !important;
    padding-top: 0 !important;
}
.wp-admin #wpabar {
     top: -28px !important;
}
.youtube-responsive-container {
position:relative;
padding-bottom:56.25%;
padding-top:30px;
height:0;
overflow:hidden;
}

.youtube-responsive-container iframe, .youtube-responsive-container object, .youtube-responsive-container embed {
position:absolute;
top:0;
left:0;
width:100%;
height:100%;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 767px) {

        .ac-content-sidebar {
                position: static;
                top: 355px;
                left: 5%;
                right: 5%;
                z-index: 20;
                width: 100%;
        }

        #content {
                margin-top: 250px;
        }

        .ac-content-sidebar #sidebar .widget {
                margin-left: 0;
                margin-right: 0;
                width: 100%;
                float: none;
        }

}
@media only screen and (min-width: 768px) {
 aside.sidebar {
  position: absolute;
  left: 40px;
  top: 255px;
 }
}
```

What I would like to do is in the mobile view, move the sidebar (recent post and archives) to the bottom of the post content and have it use the full width of the page and have the content use the full width of the page as well.

Thanks in advance for any tips or assistance.

Comment: Maybe on the mobile media query you could use flexbox & place one below the other like that? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33329225/placing-a-div-below-another-using-flexbox

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The aside element in ac-content-sidebar has a max-width set of 250px and a width of 30%.

If you add the following css rules to your query for everything below 767px, it'll go full width.

```
.ac-content-sidebar > aside{
  width: 100%;
  max-width: none;
}

div#ac-main-content{
  width: 100%;
}
```

[image]

Now, as for re-ordering the elements, that's a bit trickier and will require a little flexbox.

For .ac-content-sidebar add the following rules:

```
display: flex;
flex-direction: column
```

For .ac-sidebar, add the following rule:

```
order: 2
```

And for .ac-main-content, add the following rule:

```
order: 1
```

That "should" do it.

Comment: Hi Jamie, Thanks for the update. The first part worked like a charm. I modified it a little to work better across different screen types but your advice really helped unstick me. In regards to the flexbox - does that go in the media query section of the css or at the start where everything is defined?

Comment: Figured it out. Thanks